# Отслеживание скролла при определённом разрешении экрана

Tags: jquery

Всем привет.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

var removeTimeoutID, $menu = $('#super');    
$(window).scroll(function() {    
    clearTimeout(removeTimeoutID);
    $menu.addClass('new-class');
    removeTimeoutID = setTimeout(function(){
        $menu.removeClass('new-class');
    }, 150);
});
 
});
```

```css
#super {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
background: #000;}

.new-class {
background: #ff0000 !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="super" class="menu">
Content
</div>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
<p>datad</p>
```

Есть такой вот код, благодаря нему горизонтальная менюшка во время скролла становится полупрозрачной.
Но есть две проблемы:

1. Не могу никак запихать это в условие, чтобы скрипт выполнялся, только если разрешение экрана в пределах 768 - 1280px. Пробовал заключить в условие

   if( $(window).width() > 768 && $(window).width() < 1280 ) {

Но тогда переставало работать вообще.
Надо чтобы скрипт реагировал на ресайзы (вышел за пределы - не исполнять, опять в пределах - работать).

2. Если находишься не у самого верха страницы и обновляешься, то блок как бы моргает, из-за того, что скрипт сначала придаёт класс, а потом удаляет.

Comment: так напиши условие в теле `$(window).scroll(function() {`

Comment: @Blacknife , да мой косяк, окно браузера не тех размеров ставил и удивлялся почему не работает)))
но пункт 2 всё еще актуален.
и ещё, почему-то нижняя граница на смартфонах не учитывается, т.е. скрипт отрабатывает на всех разрешениях до 1280. В js есть что-то типа viewport'а как в css media?